# How do I lay my DIVs in a unique grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, algorithm

Currently, my DIVS are laid out like this. It's basic `float:left`. Easy

[image: http://imgur.com/FSiTs.jpg]

But what if I want to turn some of those square DIVs into one that is twice as wide/long?  They will be randomly selected, of course. How would I generate the HTML/javascript and do this?

[image: http://imgur.com/XsYLV.jpg]

What's the math behind this? Will `float:left` still work?

Can someone please give a good example of how this can be achieved easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Masonry works well for this: http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/ ([demo](http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/))

Comment: If I define my DIV sizes into just those sizes...will it look really well "fit" ? Masonry looks like there are gaps.

Comment: I think if you have pre-defined sizes they will fit even better. Check out the puma site for example: http://www.puma.com/running/media

Comment: jyoseph, this is great, thanks! Do you know if there's something like this for the iPhone SDK?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything. I've only dabbled in iPhone development. Sorry!